# The configuration of Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

By using amazon web service, I created a cluster consists of four nodes as the following:
- one node as a master node (RAM 1GB, CPU 1 core, HDD 8 GB)
- Three nodes as slave nodes and each node specification 
(RAM 2GB, CPU 2 core, HDD 8 GB)

My questions:
- How can I configure this cluster correctly?
- How many containers can work concurrently?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure cluster with your specifications. No of container vary with the available resource such as RAM and CPU.

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html

Find above link to get detailed understanding on containers.